# How to add ItemsSource to Combobox nested in ListBox Template from codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, listbox

I have some problem with `ComboBox` nested in `ListBox`. I want to add the same `ItemsSource`(gained from database, adding from codebehind) to each of `comboboxes` created in `ListBox`, but don't know how. Any ideas how to do this?

```
</Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="lbxKey" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type1}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="200" Text="{Binding NAMETYPE1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
                        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Tag="{Binding IDTYPE1}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                                <!-- no idea what should be here or even if this is needed -->
                            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Type2}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NAMETYPE2}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

In codebehind:

```
lbxListbox.ItemsSource = observableCollectionFromDatabase;
//here should be sth to set ItemsSource for comboboxes in ListBox
```

Comment: Sb suggested to set combobox `ItemsSource` as `ListBox.DataContext` and set Items to DataContext but i don't know why this answer was deleted.

`ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},Path=DataContext}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a collection type property in your item class (anything that implements `IEnumerable` will do). Then you would bind the ComboBox's `ItemSource` like this:

```
<ComboBox Tag="{Binding IDTYPE1}" ItemsSource="{Binding ITEMS}" ...>
```

Comment: But unfortunatelly there is none. This `listbox` is being built on three tables from database - one with `TYPE1`, one with `TYPE2` and something similar to hash table between them and I can't change `TYPE1` and `TYPE2` classes.

Comment: Then you should create an appropriate view model. Search the web for MVVM.

Comment: It's probably more apropriate than using `DataContext` in `ListBox` as container for `Combobox ItemsSource`. Thanks for help.